# Performing calculations by level in R

Tags: r, levels

I'm trying to perform calculations based off a certain level in my data frame.

```
YEAR    MONTH   CARRIER ORIGIN  DEST    DEP_DELAY   ARR_DELAY   CANCELLED   
1   2014    1   AA  JFK LAX 14  13  0
2   2014    1   AA  JFK LAX -3  1   0   
3   2014    1   AA  JFK LAX NA  NA  1   
4   2014    1   AA  JFK LAX 65  59  0   
5   2014    1   AA  JFK LAX 110 110 0   
6   2014    1   AA  JFK LAX 17  -8  0   
7   2014    1   AA  JFK LAX 10  -13 0
```

For example, I want to group by `$CARRIER` and find out how many times each carrier had a flight delay. I also want to calculate other things, like mean arrival delays, etc.
Can anyone show me how to perform calculations by level in R?
Thanks!
Hannah

Comment: Ahh the airlines data.  I spent many long nights crunching this data in college

Answer (score 2):

There are several different ways to do this. Depending upon your ultimate goals, different approaches offer different advantages.

Here's a comparison of three approaches, using a [reproducible result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with dummy data:

```
## Create data
d <- data.frame(CARRIER   = as.factor(c("a", "b",  "a", "c", "b", "a", "c")),
                DEP_DELAY = as.factor(c("Y",  "N", "N", NA, "Y", "N" ,  "Y")),
                ARR_DELAY = as.factor(c("N",  "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y")),
                CANCELLED = as.factor(c("N",  "N", "N", "N", NA, "Y", "Y")))
```

1) The `aggregate` function in base R is the perhaps the simplest way to get what you want and I would recommend using it if this is all you want to do:

```
aggregate(DEP_DELAY ~ CARRIER, d, summary)
    # CARRIER DEP_DELAY.N DEP_DELAY.Y
# 1       a           2           1
# 2       b           1           1 
# 3       c           0           1
```

2) The `plyr` package uses a different syntax than base R, but is very powerful. It was written by the Hadley Wickham who wrote the `ggplot2` plotting package. The befits of `plyr` would be its powerful syntax (base R can become clunky when you start to do complicated summaries) and usefulness in manipulating data for `ggplot2` (because Wickham wrote both of them and they compliment each other nicely).

```
library(plyr) # you will need to install this package
ddply(d, .(CARRIER, DEP_DELAY), summary)
#   CARRIER DEP_DELAY ARR_DELAY CANCELLED
#1    a:2       N:2       N:1       N:1  
#2    b:0       Y:0       Y:1       Y:1  
#3    c:0        <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
#4    a:1       N:0       N:1       N:1  
# I clipped the output to save space
```

3) The `data.tables` package uses a third syntax. Like`plyr`, it is a powerful library that has its own syntax. Its befit over `plyr` is that it can handle much larger data sets due to different memory usage in the code.

```
library(data.table) # You'll also need to install this package
DT = data.table(d) # Convert data.frame to data.table
DT[,summary(DEP_DELAY), by = CARRIER]
#   CARRIER V1
#1:       a  2
#2:       a  1
#3:       b  1
#4:       b  1
#5:       c  0
#6:       c  1
#7:       c  1
```

If you're just learning R, I would suggest method 1. If you use `R` more, I suggest learning both because each can be advantageous to have in your toolbox. If you're using larger data sets (~100s MB or larger), I would learn `data.table` first. If you're wanting to learn `ggplot2`, I would learn `plyr' first.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `tapply()` function.

For example let's say your data.frame is called `data`. Then you can use:

`tapply(data$DEP_DELAY, data$CARRIER, function(x) length(na.omit(x)))` to find how many times each carrier had a flight delay.

`tapply(data$ARR_DELAY, data$CARRIER, mean, na.rm=TRUE)` to find out mean arrival delays.